# CNAME in Route 53 - Redirect www to non-www not working

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, amazon-route53

I'm hosting web application on AWS with `Nginx 1.6.3` and `django 1.7.6`

I'd like to redirect `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com` through Route 53

In other words, showing `mydomain.com/foo` on address bar when user typed `www.mydomain.com/foo`

---

**Route 53 Configuration**

`mydomain.com`

- Type : A record
- Value : ALIAS {Elastic Load Balancer A record}

`www.mydomain.com`

- Type : CNAME
- Value : mydomain.com

---

With above configuration, `mydomain.com` is well working but `www.mydomain.com` returns **400 Bad request** error. Of course, I've tried it on secret mode(cache-free) with enough time interval(more than 24 hrs). Adding `http://` at front returns same error.

---

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }
```

If I added above code at `nginx.conf`, `www.mydomain.com` redirected to `mydomain.com` as I expected. **However, I'm not sure that editing web server configuration is necessary to use CNAME service.** How can I use CNAME service without editing web server?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the web server configuration. Though, you should be redirecting from no-www to www; you have it backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like expected behavior. Exactly what happens when the HTTP server receives a request that it does not know how to deal with can differ, but no redirect is expected unless it happens at the HTTP level.

A `CNAME` record is merely stating that a given name in DNS is an alias of a different name in DNS.

What happens when you have a `CNAME` record in place is that when your HTTP client makes an `A` or `AAAA` query for the alias name they will get the IP address associated with the actual name returned.

They will then connect to that address, knowing it is the address associated with the name they looked up (the alias) and make an entirely normal request.

When you have name-based virtual hosts, what the HTTP server cares about is what the `Host` header says and the client will put whatever hostname that was in the URL it navigated to as the value of that header (in this example, the alias).

If you want to redirect an HTTP client you need an HTTP redirect, like that in your own example.